# POWERSHELL - Enable ntfs compression of subfolders without knowing parent folder name

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to enable NTFS compression on different subfolders, while having parent folders that can have different name.

Here is what I've tried so far :

```
$test = "D:\azerty\temp\sandbox_del_old\*\uiop\"
If((Test-Path $test))
{
      Get-ChildItem -Path $test -Recurse -Directory | ForEach-Object {
        compact /C /f $_.FullName
      }
}
```

What I want in the end is compress every subfolders (and files) in ...\uiop\

When I execute the script, it compress every folders and files in D:\azerty so first, this is wrong. And it doesn't even compress subfolders and "sub"files.

I can't find it working with my beginner powershell knowledge...

Can anyone help me please ? :)

**EDIT : Managed to get it to "work" with adding -Directory (edited). But text files after those subdirectories are not compressed**

Comment: You can't start with something like "./" ?

Comment: @Elikill58 may detail a bit ? Tried ./uiop\ but it does nothing. I think "./" have to be used when you execute the script in the current directory, which I won't.

Comment: It won't do files cause of the `-Directory` switch. It honestly should work as is, unless you try Powershells way of doing it: [Powershell Compression](https://powershell.one/wmi/root/cimv2/cim_datafile-Compress). Try adding a `Start-Sleep ` to see if it does anything different

Answer (score 2):

You can compress the FILES without relying on compact.exe. This example ignores the directory compression attribute. A side effect: Works with unicode files and with files which include spaces.
See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winioctl/ni-winioctl-fsctl_set_compression as well.

```text
$MethodDefinition= @'
public static class FileTools
{
  private const int FSCTL_SET_COMPRESSION = 0x9C040;
  private const short COMPRESSION_FORMAT_DEFAULT = 1;
  private const short COMPRESSION_FORMAT_DISABLE = 0;

  [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
  private static extern int DeviceIoControl(
      IntPtr hDevice,
      int dwIoControlCode,
      ref short lpInBuffer,
      int nInBufferSize,
      IntPtr lpOutBuffer,
      int nOutBufferSize,
      ref int lpBytesReturned,
      IntPtr lpOverlapped);

  public static bool Compact(IntPtr handle)
  {
    int lpBytesReturned = 0;
    short lpInBuffer = COMPRESSION_FORMAT_DEFAULT;

    return DeviceIoControl(handle, FSCTL_SET_COMPRESSION,
        ref lpInBuffer, sizeof(short), IntPtr.Zero, 0,
        ref lpBytesReturned, IntPtr.Zero) != 0;
  }
  public static bool Uncompact(IntPtr handle)
  {
    int lpBytesReturned = 0;
    short lpInBuffer = COMPRESSION_FORMAT_DISABLE;

    return DeviceIoControl(handle, FSCTL_SET_COMPRESSION,
        ref lpInBuffer, sizeof(short), IntPtr.Zero, 0,
        ref lpBytesReturned, IntPtr.Zero) != 0;
  }
}
'@

$Kernel32 = Add-Type -MemberDefinition $MethodDefinition -Name ‘Kernel32’ -Namespace ‘Win32’ -PassThru

$filespec = "c:\folder\*.log"

# compact anything that is not yet compacted
foreach ($File in (Get-ChildItem -Path $filespec -Recurse -File).Where({$_.Attributes  -notmatch [System.IO.FileAttributes]::Compressed})) {
    $FileObject = [System.IO.File]::Open($File.FullName,'Open','ReadWrite','None')
    $Method = [Win32.Kernel32+FileTools]::Compact($FileObject.Handle)
    $FileObject.Close()
}

# decompact
foreach ($File in (Get-ChildItem -Path $filespec -Recurse -File).Where({$_.Attributes  -match [System.IO.FileAttributes]::Compressed})) {
    $FileObject = [System.IO.File]::Open($File.FullName,'Open','ReadWrite','None')
    $Method = [Win32.Kernel32+FileTools]::Uncompact($FileObject.Handle)
    $FileObject.Close()
}
```